# Send post-request from dockerized jar to local python-service

Tags: spring-boot, flask, jar, docker-image, connection-refused

I am running a dockerized jar and a local flask-service on my Mac. The jar represents a web-app for a musical catalogue and the flask-service transforms musical notes into a xml-based music-encoding format. The service is called when the user has clicked on the download button.
Starting the application through PyCharm and IntelliJ works fine, but within the container I get:

```
  2019-11-30 19:36:14.504 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[. 
  [/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet 
  [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request 
  processing failed; nested exception is 
  org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on 
  POST request for "http://0.0.0.0:5000/test": Connection refused 
  (Connection refused); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: 
  Connection refused (Connection refused)] with root cause

  java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:540) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:182) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:474) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:569) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:341) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:362) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1248) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1187) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1081) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:1015) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:76) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:735) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:670) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:414) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at com.masterarbeit.wolfganggabrielvz.adapter.userRoles.MEIAdapter.getData(MEIAdapter.java:51) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at com.masterarbeit.wolfganggabrielvz.adapter.controller.IncipitController.getMei(IncipitController.java:51) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

This is the dockerfile from the Spring-Boot app:

```
FROM amazoncorretto:11
ADD target/springbootapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar springbootapp- 
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar","springbootapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

How I built the image:

```
docker build -f Dockerfile -t catalogue_image .
```

I load the image and linked it with the mysql-db

```
docker run --name catalogue_image -p 8080:8080 -d --link catalogueDB:mysql catalogue_image
```

The network-settings of the running container:

```
"NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "",
        "SandboxID": "56bd5ecdaab28c726711b368f0fa73a1d181d66605056cdfbecce0188bd7c1f5",
        "HairpinMode": false,
        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "Ports": {
            "8080/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "8080"
                }
            ]
        },
        "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/56bd5ecdaab2",
        "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
        "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
        "EndpointID": "b0366c7e1b934208f7eb748d58cc18dac76a94d5da3e09184761d6da38c52373",
        "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
        "IPPrefixLen": 16,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
        "Networks": {
            "bridge": {
                "IPAMConfig": null,
                "Links": null,
                "Aliases": null,
                "NetworkID": "eda38ae3c3fc27a3990e3761dc7f35ddd98f04e9f6e55cce46e191557df688d8",
                "EndpointID": "b0366c7e1b934208f7eb748d58cc18dac76a94d5da3e09184761d6da38c52373",
                "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                "IPv6Gateway": "",
                "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                "DriverOpts": null
            }
        }
```

Flask runs on my local-machine. It does not return any Error-Code after a service-call fails:

```
      python3 gateway.py
    ['/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/Users/max/PycharmProjects/flaskmicroservice/app',         '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python37.zip',             '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7',               '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-             dynload', '/Users/max/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages',                                     '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/verovio-             2.0.0-py3.7-macosx-10.13-x86_64.egg']
    * Serving Flask app "gateway" (lazy loading)
    * Environment: production
    WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
    Use a production WSGI server instead.
    * Debug mode: off
    * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Before, I got a FileNotFound-Exception but I could already fix it by changing the resources path. I also entered the container and added localhost under etc/hosts but it did not work. I read all the other solutions about accessing a local service from inside a container but in did not solve my problem.

I would be grateful for every help!

EDIT:
I am using a docker-compose file now

```
version: "3"
services:
db:
   image: mysql:latest
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=crescendo
    - MYSQL_USER=root
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=crescendo
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=wolfgang_gabriel_db
  ports:
     - 3306:3306

web:
  image: gabriel_verzeichnis
  depends_on:
    - db

  ports:
    - 8080:8080
  domainname: localhost
  network_mode: "host"
  environment:
    - DATABASE_HOST=db
    - DATABASE_USER=root
    - DATABASE_PASSWORD=crescendo
    - DATABASE_NAME=wolfgang_gabriel_db
    - DATABASE_PORT=3306

  links:
    - db:3306
```

Regarding the answer, I tried to set the network_mode as host in order to get access to my local machine, but it did not work. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO. Almost none of this code is useful in diagnosing this problem. Your problem is in how you run the docker container and the flask. Can you clear out the code and show us that instead please? The error message is still useful though, and the fact that you're connecting to 0.0.0.0:5000 from within the java container. Thx.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry for the inconveniences. I edit my post and add new infos. I hope it helps

Comment: No need to apologise. We're here to help. I've posted an answer, feel free to ask questions.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem here is that you're running your client in a docker container and your server on your host machine, and you haven't arranged to route traffic between them.

By default, a container is its own localhost. So when you access 0.0.0.0 it maps back to the container you're accessing it from. You want to reference the host so that you can access a service there. This is not a great idea but is possible using `--network host` flag. This is such a bad idea that I will offer you an alternative.

A good solution is to also run flask in a container and have its address passed as an environment variable to the client container. You can do this in any number of ways (including as a flag on the command-line for the client), but one of the easiest is to use docker-compose and put both services in the compose file, then your url would reference the hostname of the flask service, rather than an IP address, and docker will ensure that traffic is correctly routed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I totally agree with you. To run it in a container was my first choice. But because of a very nasty "ModuleNotFound" error, that was caused by a third party module, I gave up and tried to run it from my local machine. I recently opened a thread about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59142262/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-verovio

Comment: By the way, I am using a docker-compose file now. Is there an option to
use --network host as well? I tried it with network_mode = "host" and network_mode = host, but it still not work.