# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'verovio'

Tags: python, docker, flask

Hi there I would like to run my flask app in a container but I got stucked caused of a third party module. (I am using PyCharm)

This is my docker file:

```
FROM python:3-alpine

MAINTAINER foo

COPY app /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python3", "gateway.py"]
```

I run the container by this command:

```
docker run --name mei_converter -p 5000:5000 mei_converter:latest
```

And receives this:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'verovio'
```

I already fixed the dependencies in order to run it on my local machine

```
Terminal: python3 gateway.py

['/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages', 
'/Users/max/PycharmProjects/flaskmicroservice/app', 
'/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python37.zip', 
'/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7', 
'/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib- 
dynload', '/Users/max/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages', 
'/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/verovio- 
2.0.0-py3.7-macosx-10.13-x86_64.egg']
* Serving Flask app "gateway" (lazy loading)
* Environment: production
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
Use a production WSGI server instead.
* Debug mode: off
* Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

This works well

I also checked the project interpreter in PyCharm and found the package as installed.

Maybe some information about this third party package could help:
It is a converter for music-encoding from these guys https://www.verovio.org/python.xhtml
and not "native python" (SWIG is necessary)
By the way.. I come from the java world and have in fact zero experience with python. I am using this flask app as an microservice for my spring boot app. 
I would be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to do in the container the same you did in your local host. That is, you need to add steps to the Dockerfile to compile verovio and use it in the container.

Answer (score 0):

As of Alpine Linux 3.17 or higher, you can just `apk add py3-verovio` to install it.

in your dockerfile, this will probably look like

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk update || apk update
RUN apk add python3 py3-verovio
```